# How would you refactor this code?

Tags: c#

How would you refactor this code?

```
double p = (Convert.ToDouble(inta) / Convert.ToDouble(intb)) * 100;
double v = (p / 100) * Convert.ToDouble(intc);
return (int)v;
```

It seems very messy to me, I know I could squeeze it onto one line but i'd be interested to know what others would do.

Thanks

Comment: Some of these answers below sadden me. :*(  He said refactor, not refuctor.

Comment: The really odd thing is that using doubles gives you rounding errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `inta`, `intb` and `intc` are typed as `int`/`Int32` then `Convert.ToDouble` is basically the same as a simple cast to `double`.

```
return (int)((inta / (double)intb) * intc);
```

Whether this is actually a worthwhile refactoring is another matter. It often makes more sense to keep intermediate calculations as separate statements to improve readability, even if you don't need those intermediate results. And, of course, having meaningful variable names makes a *big* difference.

Comment: +1 - For beating me to the answer. As well as adding a bit of pragmatic advice.

Answer (score 4):

Seriously, don't. What's wrong with the code as it is - ignoring possible mathematical problems and *just* looking at the code structure itself?

I wouldn't refactor. Squeezing it all on to one line would make it a lot harder to read. If I *absolutely had* to do something, I'd create new variables for the double versions of a, b, and c like this:

```
//set up variables
double doubleA = Convert.ToDouble(inta);
double doubleB = Convert.ToDouble(intb);
double doubleC = Convert.ToDouble(intc);


//do calculations
double p = (doubleA / doubleB) * 100
double v = (p / 100) * doubleC; //why did we divide by 100 when we multiplied by it on the line above?
return (int)v; //why are we casting back to int after all the fuss and bother with doubles?
```

but really I'd rather just leave it alone!

Comment: I would give the variables a more meaningful name, apart from that, this gets a +1 for me

Comment: @Zac: I'd like more meaningful names too, but in this context it's impossible to know their true meanings.

Answer (score 4):

Well, for a start I'd use more meaningful names, and at a guess this is taking a ratio of integers, converting it to a percentage, applying that percentage to another original value, and returning a new value, which is the result truncated to an integer.

```
double percent = (Convert.ToDouble( numer ) / Convert.ToDouble( denom )) * 100;
double value = (percent / 100) * Convert.ToDouble( originalValue );
return (int)value;
```

One difference between using Convert and a cast is that Convert will throw an exception for out of bounds, but casting won't, and casting to int results in Int32.MinValue. So if `value` is too big or too little for an int, or `Infinity` or `NaN`, you will get Int32.MinValue rather than an exception at the end. The other converts can't fail, as any int can be represented as a double.

So you could write it using casts with no change in meaning, and exploit the fact that in an expression involving ints and doubles the ints are cast to doubles automatically:

```
double percent = ((double) numer ) /  denom ) * 100;
double value = (percent / 100) * originalValue;
return (int)value;
```

Now, C# truncates double results on assignment to 15-16 but it's implementation defined whether intermediates are operated at higher precision. I don't think that will change the output within the range that can be cast to an int, but I don't know, and the value space is too large for an exhaustive test.  So without having a specification for *exactly* what the function is intended to do, there is very little else you can change and be sure that you will not change the output.

If you compare these refactorings, each of which are naively mathematical equivalent, and run a range of values through them:

```
    static int test0(int numer, int denom, int initialValue)
    {
        double percent = (Convert.ToDouble(numer) / Convert.ToDouble(denom)) * 100;
        double value = (percent / 100) * Convert.ToDouble(initialValue);
        return (int)value;
    }

    static int test1(int numer, int denom, int initialValue)
    {
        return (int)((((((double)numer) / denom) * 100 ) / 100 ) * initialValue);
    }

    static int test2(int numer, int denom, int initialValue)
    {
        return (int)((((double)numer) / denom) * initialValue);
    }

    static int test3(int numer, int denom, int initialValue)
    {
        return (int)((((double)numer) * initialValue) / denom);
    }

    static int test4(int numer, int denom, int initialValue)
    {
        if (denom == 0) return int.MinValue;
        return (numer * initialValue / denom);
    }
```

Then you get the following result of counting the number of times `testN` does not equal `test0` and letting it run a few hours:

```
numer in [-10000,10000] 
denom in [-10000,0) (0,10000] 
initialValue in [-10000,-8709] # will get to +10000 eventually

test1 fails = 0 of 515428330128 tests, 100% accuracy.
test2 fails = 110365664 of 515428330128 tests, 99.9785875828803% accuracy.
test3 fails = 150082166 of 515428330128 tests, 99.9708820495057% accuracy.
test4 fails = 150082166 of 515428330128 tests, 99.9708820495057% accuracy.
```

So if you want an exactly equivalent function, then it seems that you can get to `test1`. Although the 100s should cancel out in `test2`, in reality they do effect the result in a few edge cases - the rounding of the intermediate values pushes value one side or the other of an integer. For this test, the input values were in the range -10000 to +10000, so the integer multiplication in `test4` doesn't overflow, so  `test3` and  `test4` are the same. For wider input ranges, test4 will deviate more often.

Always verify your refactoring against automated tests. And don't assume that the values worked on by computers behave like the numbers in high-school mathematics.

Comment: Oh, and btw, all failures happen for `numer*initialValue%denom==0`? (Ignoring overflows).

Answer (score 1):

First I will give p, v, inta, intb etc. meaningful names.

First two lines can be combined:

```
double pv = ((double)inta/intb)*intc;
return (int)pv;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (int)(Convert.ToDouble(inta * intc) / Convert.ToDouble(intb));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (int)(((double)inta / intb) * intc);
```

**(Fixed)**

Comment: Whoops, my (double) cast was on the wrong side of the parentheses.

Comment: Just delete it; with your edit, it is the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is just

```
inta * intc / intb
```

If you don't need the value of p explicitly, you don't need to do any casting at all.

Comment: not really, the division must be double otherwise you may loose precision

Comment: He is not. Try `int a=286, b=14, c=91`. Gives 1858 vs 1859. Double value was `1858.9999999999998`, due to rounding errors.

Comment: Which is an error on the double value, so he's even more right

Comment: @Dogget - That would be a **fix**, not refactoring. This fix might break other code, that somehow depends on 'wrong' outcome.

Comment: And it might cause an integer overflow not present in the double code.

Comment: @Ishtar it seems to give the same answer as the original 99.971% of the time, whereas the LukeH's refactoring does so 99.979% of the time. If the  requirements allow an discrepancy in at most one in four thousand cases, then there is a difference between this and the accepted answer, but if you want something with zero discrepancies, then the accepted answer is also invalid.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @FrustratedWithFormsDes's answer:

```
double doubleA = (double) (inta * intc);
double doubleB = (double) intb;

return (int) (doubleA / doubleB);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few interesting points that nobody else seems to have covered, so I'll add to the mix...

- The first refactoring I'd do is to use good naming. Three lines of code is fine, but "p", "v", and "inta" are terrible names.
- Convert.ToXXX could throw exceptions if "inta" et al are not convertible to double. In that case, you'd use double.TryParse() or a try...catch to make this code robust for any type. (Of course, as mentioned by many, if the values are just ints, then a (double) cast will suffice).
- If intb has the value 0, then you will get a divide by zero exception. So you might wish to to check if intb is nonzero before using it.
- So to the maths... The *100 and /100 will cancel out so are pointless. Assuming the inputs are integers (and not huge), then if you premultiply inta by intc before doing the divide, you can eliminate one (double) operation, as (int * intc) can be safely done at integer precision.

So (assuming non-huge int values, and accepting that we might throw a div-by-zero exception) the end result (without renaming for clarity) could be:

```
return((int) ((inta * intc) / (double) intb));
```

It's not a lot different from the accepted answer, but on some platforms could perform slightly better (by using an integer multiply instead of a double one).